# How do I connect to external API from Magento

Tags: soap, magento-1.7

I am looking for some assistance in creating an API based module to push customer information out of Magento into a Third party loyalty program.

So far I have created a basic module but cannot find any good information on creating API based modules in Magento and could really do with some advice please...

I need to somehow hook into the Checkout success page in Magneto and add a form the will POST the customers information (name, address etc) to a third party loyalty program. I also need to be able to login to complete the billing information etc...

Does anyone know of any handy tutorials or documentation for such an implementation?

So far I have setup an API user with the appropriate roles. I have also created a very basic module for test purpses but browsing to the file I get a 404 error

apitest.php

```
<?php 
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://mysite.com/api/?wsdl'); //edit the address and put the url to your magento here

$sessionId = $proxy->login('######', '#######'); // put in the info for your user here

echo "Login ID : $sessionId";
$result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'Mymodule.testConnection', array('param1' => ' This string was sent from soap client'));
echo $result;
```

Objectmodel/api.php

```
<?php
class MyModule_MyModule_Model_ObjectModel_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{
    public function testConnection($arg)
    {
        return "Hello World! My argument is : " . $arg;
    }
}
```

I followed the example from [here](http://bananacode.com.br/magento-custom-api-module-with-acl/) for getting a basic 'Hello world' module up and running if anyone could assist me with getting the correct setup I would be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of connect magento API you can create customer like this.

```
define('INCLUDE_PATH', '/var/www/QA/mojostage/app/');
define('INCLUDE_FILE', 'Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId($wesite_id);
        $customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);
        /*
         * Check if the email exist on the system.
         * If YES,  it will not create a user account.
         */

        if (!$customer->getId()) {

            //setting data such as email, firstname, lastname, and password

            $customer->setEmail($customer_email);
            $customer->setTaxvat($value['cus_vatnumber'])
                    ->setCreatedAt($date1)
                    ->setDob($value['date_of_birth'])
                    ->setGroupId($cus_group_id)
                    ->setConfirmation($is_active)
                    ->setCreatedIn('Admin')
                    ->setStoreId($store_id)
                    ->setWebsiteId($wesite_id)
                    ->setEntityId($value['cus_id']);
            $customer->setFirstname($customer_fname);
            $customer->setLastname($customer_lname);
            $customer->setPassword($value['password']);

            $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber');
            $subscriber->setStoreId($store_id)
                    ->setCustomerId($value['cus_id'])
                    ->setSubscriberEmail($customer_email)
                    ->setSubscriberStatus($value['cus_spam'])
                    ->setSubscriberConfirmCode($subscriber->randomSequence());
        }

        //the save the data and send the new account email.
        $customer->save();
        $subscriber->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not sure which file I need to create and place your code?